# GROCERY or GROSHERY

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, dialects

I am from Minnesota and have always pronounced GROCERY as GROSH-RY. I teach grammar and pronunciation online, and I recently encountered much controversy regarding what is the correct or incorrect pronunciation of this word. According to [YOUGLISH.COM](https://youglish.com/pronounce/grocery/english/us) which offers a multitude of real-life examples, my pronunciation is not in the minority. If it is so widespread, why insist that it is wrong? If English is a fluid language, and a high percentage of otherwise well-educated people pronounce a word in a specific way, wouldn´t that make it correct?